# How many MPs have lost their seat in an election and subsequently been promoted to the House of Lords?

Tags: united-kingdom, house-of-lords

According to the [electoral reform society](https://www.electoral-reform.org.uk/campaigns/elected-house-of-lords/) Nearly 1/3 of current members of the House of Lords were politicians before their elevation.

> In the current House of Lords, 29 percent of peers were politicians before entering the Lords – with the majority being former MPs. A further eight percent of peers are former political staff or held senior positions in political parties.

What it does not mention and I can't see to find collected anywhere is how many of these Lords were, like [Zac Goldsmith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zac_Goldsmith), politicians removed from the House of Commons by the electorate.

> He was defeated at the 2019 general election, again by Sarah Olney, with a majority of 7,766 votes. After the election, Boris Johnson awarded Goldsmith with a life peerage, making him a member of the House of Lords and allowing him to retain his ministerial position.

How many MPs have lost their seat in an election and subsequently been promoted to the House of Lords?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a script to whizz through the [list of current members of the House of Lords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_members_of_the_House_of_Lords) on Wikipedia which produced the following list of 61 former MPs who subsequently lost their seat at an election, and who now sit in the Lords. Twenty-five represent the Conservatives, nineteen Labour, thirteen the Liberal Democrats, two the Democratic Unionist Party, one sits as a crossbencher, and one is non-affiliated.

I have noted the party they currently represent in the Lords rather than the party they represented in the Commons, as many have switched parties - particularly a lot of the Liberal Democrats who were previously members of Labour and then the SDP. Another example, Baron Horam, represented Labour, the SDP, and then the Conservatives in the Commons.

Notes:
<sup>1</sup> - Constituency abolished, contested a different seat and lost.
<sup>2</sup> - Lost their seat but were later re-elected to the Commons.
<sup>3</sup> - Contested a different seat (old constituency not abolished) and lost.

| Name | Party in the Lords | Date seat lost | Date of Appointment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Michael Ancram<sup>2</sup> | Conservative | Oct 1974, 1987 | 2010 |
| Gavin Barwell | Conservative | 2017 | 2023 |
| Michael Bates<sup>1</sup> | Conservative | 1997 | 2021 |
| Henry Bellingham<sup>2</sup> | Conservative | 1997 | 2020 |
| Nicola Blackwood | Conservative | 2017 | 2019 |
| Keith Bradley | Labour | 2005 | 2006 |
| Angela Bray | Conservative | 2015 | 2022 |
| Lorely Burt | Liberal Democrat | 2015 | 2015 |
| Matthew Carrington<sup>1</sup> | Conservative | 1997 | 2013 |
| Jenny Chapman | Labour | 2019 | 2021 |
| Katy Clark | Labour | 2015 | 2020 |
| David Clark<sup>2</sup> | Labour | 1974 | 2001 |
| Vernon Coaker | Labour | 2019 | 2021 |
| Brian Cotter | Liberal Democrat | 2005 | 2006 |
| Bryan Davies<sup>2</sup> | Labour | 1979 | 1997 |
| Nigel Dodds | DUP | 2019 | 2020 |
| Alf Dubs | Labour | 1987 | 1994 |
| Hugh Dykes | Liberal Democrat | 1997 | 2004 |
| Graham Evans | Conservative | 2017 | 2022 |
| Lynne Featherstone | Liberal Democrat | 2015 | 2015 |
| Frank Field | Crossbencher | 2019 | 2020 |
| Michael Forsyth | Conservative | 1997 | 1999 |
| Zac Goldsmith<sup>2</sup> | Conservative | 2016, 2019 | 2020 |
| Bruce Grocott<sup>2</sup> | Labour | 1979 | 2001 |
| John Gummer<sup>2</sup> | Conservative | 1974 | 2010 |
| Alan Haselhurst<sup>2</sup> | Conservative | 1974 | 2018 |
| Helene Hayman | Labour | 1979 | 1996 |
| Sue Hayman | Labour | 2019 | 2020 |
| Robert Hayward | Conservative | 1992 | 2015 |
| Robin Hodgson | Conservative | 1979 | 2000 |
| John Horam | Conservative | 1983 | 2013 |
| David Hunt | Conservative | 1997 | 1997 |
| Stewart Jackson | Conservative | 2017 | 2022 |
| Oona King | Labour | 2005 | 2021 |
| Timothy Kirkhope | Conservative | 1997 | 2016 |
| James Knight | Labour | 2010 | 2010 |
| Susan Kramer | Liberal Democrat | 2010 | 2010 |
| Norman Lamont<sup>1</sup> | Conservative | 1997 | 1998 |
| John Lee | Liberal Democrat | 1992 | 2006 |
| William McCrea<sup>2</sup> | DUP | 1997, 2001, 2015 | 2018 |
| Tom McNally | Liberal Democrat | 1983 | 1995 |
| Francis Maude<sup>2</sup> | Conservative | 1992 | 2015 |
| Gillian Merron | Labour | 2010 | 2021 |
| Colin Moynihan | Conservative | 1992 | 1997 |
| Michael Morris | Conservative | 1997 | 2020 |
| Chris Patten | Conservative | 1992 | 2005 |
| David Prior | Non-affiliated | 2001 | 2022 |
| Margaret Ritchie | Labour | 2017 | 2019 |
| Bill Rodgers<sup>1</sup> | Liberal Democrat | 1983 | 1992 |
| Ted Rowlands<sup>2</sup> | Labour | 1970 | 2004 |
| Ruth Smeeth | Labour | 2019 | 2022 |
| Angela Smith<sup>1</sup> | Labour | 2010 | 2010 |
| Nicol Stephen | Liberal Democrat | 1992 | 2011 |
| Dick Taverne | Liberal Democrat | Oct 1974 | 1996 |
| Ann Taylor<sup>2 3</sup> | Labour | 1983 | 2005 |
| John Thurso | Liberal Democrat | 2015 | 2016 |
| John Tomlinson | Labour | 1979 | 1998 |
| Graham Tope | Liberal Democrat | Feb 1974 | 1994 |
| William Waldegrave | Conservative | 1997 | 1999 |
| James Wharton | Conservative | 2017 | 2020 |
| Ian Wrigglesworth | Liberal Democrat | 1987 | 2013 |